# 2 Cameras giving different distributions of same image

Tags: machine-learning, distributions

I have two feature extraction pipelines giving the same features but with different distributions. To make it simple, it's like we have two types of cameras. We train the model on data coming from the first camera and want to deploy it on the second one. How can we transform images from second camera so they maych the distribution of images of first camera?

Comment: The answer to this question crucially depends on how the two cameras are different and what you mean by “transform.” Please [edit] to explain what problem you’re trying to solve in specific terms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard answer so I'm giving you my ideas.
You have two scenarios:

1. Check how the features between the two pipelines differ. If you are able to understand how they differ you may be able to transform features from one class to another
2. If not, build a ML pipeline to infer such relation. In particular, train a ML algorithm that takes as input the features of one algorithm (and maybe the input data of the feature extraction algorithm if you have it) and tries to predict the features extracted from the second feature extraction algorithm.

In the second way I assumed that you have access to both feature extraction algorithms and possibly on the input image as well, but you should be able to adapt the technique in other cases as well (leave a comment with your setup in case and I may modify my answer).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am already working on the first suggestion as it looks for me the most reliable. For the second suggestion, it is not possible for my case since I don't have access to both feature extraction algorithms.

Comment: You would need only their outputs on the same input instance, which is not exactly as having access to them both